# Django calculate field based on two other fields in formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two forms OrderHeaderForm and OrderLineForm. The OrderHeaderForm shows the customer and the totalprice. The OrderLineForm is a formset which shows the product, quantity, price and total.

I am trying to calculate the total of the line in the OrderLineForm (quantity * price). Preferably re-calculating the total when quantity or price is adjusted, but i am lost in how to create and show this calculation. Any directional tips or hints on how to implement such a thing would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: i got it working, see edited code below, but this seems to me to be a 'dirty' way of calculating form fields. Also calculations at this time only occour after POST. Any suggestions on a cleaner and/or realtime way of doing this calculation?**

New Code in models.py:

```
def linetotalprice(self):
    linetotalprice = self.orderline_product_price * self.orderline_quantity
    return linetotalprice
```

New Code in views.py

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    saveform = form.save(commit=False)
    saveform.save()
    formset.save()
    orderheader = OrderHeader.objects.get(pk=orderid.pk)
    orderlines = OrderLine.objects.filter(orderheader=orderid)
    orderheader.orderheader_total_price = 0
    for orderline in orderlines:  
        orderline.orderline_total_price = orderline.linetotalprice()
        orderheader.orderheader_total_price += orderline.linetotalprice()
        orderline.save()
        orderheader.save()
```

My models.py

```
class OrderHeader(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    orderheader_total_price = models.DecimalField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.pk)

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    orderheader = models.ForeignKey(OrderHeader)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    material = models.ForeignKey(ProductMaterial)
    orderline_quantity = models.DecimalField()
    orderline_product_price = models.DecimalField()
    orderline_total_price = models.DecimalField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.pk)

    def linetotalprice(self):
        linetotalprice = self.orderline_product_price * self.orderline_quantity
        return linetotalprice
```

my views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderHeaderForm(request.POST, instance=orderid)
    formset = OrderLineFormSet(request.POST,instance=orderid)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        form.save()
        formset.save()
        orderheader = OrderHeader.objects.get(pk=orderid.pk)
        orderlines = OrderLine.objects.filter(orderheader=orderid)
        orderheader.orderheader_total_price = 0
        for orderline in orderlines:  
            orderline.orderline_total_price = orderline.linetotalprice()
            orderheader.orderheader_total_price += orderline.linetotalprice()
            orderline.save()
            orderheader.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Order saved')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Order save error, please check fields below')
else:
    form = OrderHeaderForm(instance=orderid)
    formset = OrderLineFormSet(instance=orderid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript to calculate and show total in that field value in real time.

In your view, you shouldn't do a query to get both created `OrderHeader` and `OrderLines`, `form.save()` return this instance

Do :

```
OrderHeader = form.save()
OrderLines  = formset.save()
```

and i prefer

```
for orderline in orderlines:  
            orderline.orderline_total_price = orderline.linetotalprice()
            orderheader.orderheader_total_price += orderline.orderline_total_price // avoid recalculating, use that value calculated just before
            orderline.save()
            //orderheader.save() avoid saving each time for this model
 orderheader.save() // saving one time :)
```

Also you can change linetotalprice function to directly return:

```
def linetotalprice(self):
    return self.orderline_product_price * self.orderline_quantity
```

and put **orderline_total_price** default value to 0